# How can I program the function keys on my MacBook to do a combination of keys (not open an application)?

Tags: macbook, automation, automator

There are other questions similar to this, but not exactly. What I want to do is to reprogram a function key on the MacBook Pro to do other key combinations. Coming from a Windows background, I terribly miss the Home and End keys. Home on a Mac is <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and End is <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>. I want to make a function key do this combination. Is this possible?

Comment: You mean you want (for example) `F1` be equivalent to `Fn ←` (thus, `Home`)?

Comment: A better match for Windows's Home and End on the Mac is ⌘← and ⌘→, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Look for something like [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) or a more-general-purpose app like [Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com/) or [Launchbar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html).